# Adding items to a listView that uses a baseAdapter in another activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a class that extends the BaseAdapter class. I want to add data from my MainActivity to the ListView in the second activity . but the listView fails to add the data. it only overrides the first one when I try adding data the second time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ListView, use RecyclerView. It reusing already created views that save your memory from view creating process. 
[Read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView)